# find all occurence of a list of strings in a big directory, fast?

Tags: linux, performance, search, grep

I have a list of a of strings,

listOfKeys.txt

```
string1
string2
string3
```

code_base/

```
lots of files
```

I want to print any matches like:

```
 filepath : string1
```

this is too slow:

```
fgrep -rio -f listOfKeys.txt . > componentsUsedInServices.txt

fgrep -ro -f listOfKeys.txt . > componentsUsedInServices.txt
```

didn't work:

```
LC_ALL=C fgrep -ro -f listOfKeys.txt . > componentsUsedInServices.txt
```

Comment: It's going to be slow simply because it has to do lots of work to search all the files. There's no getting around it.

Comment: When you say "this is too slow", how slow was it, and how fast do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1):

Give [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#Installation) a try. It's heavily optimized for speed. Here are some [sample benchmarks](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/README.md#quick-examples-comparing-tools) from its README:

> This example searches the entire
> [Linux kernel source tree](https://github.com/BurntSushi/linux)
> (after running `make defconfig && make -j8`) for `[A-Z]+_SUSPEND`, where
> all matches must be words. Timings were collected on a system with an Intel
> i7-6900K 3.2 GHz.
>
> Please remember that a single benchmark is never enough! See my
> [blog post on ripgrep](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)
> for a very detailed comparison with more benchmarks and analysis.
>
> | Tool | Command | Line count | Time |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ripgrep (Unicode) | `rg -n -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 452 | **0.136s** |
> | [git grep](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html) | `git grep -P -n -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 452 | 0.348s |
> | [ugrep (Unicode)](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) | `ugrep -r --ignore-files --no-hidden -I -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 452 | 0.506s |
> | [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) | `ag -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 452 | 0.654s |
> | [git grep](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html) | `LC_ALL=C git grep -E -n -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 452 | 1.150s |
> | [ack](https://github.com/beyondgrep/ack3) | `ack -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 452 | 4.054s |
> | [git grep (Unicode)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html) | `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 git grep -E -n -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 452 | 4.205s |
>
> Here's another benchmark on the same corpus as above that disregards gitignore
> files and searches with a whitelist instead. The corpus is the same as in the
> previous benchmark, and the flags passed to each command ensure that they are
> doing equivalent work:
>
> | Tool | Command | Line count | Time |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ripgrep | `rg -uuu -tc -n -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 388 | **0.096s** |
> | [ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) | `ugrep -r -n --include='*.c' --include='*.h' -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 388 | 0.493s |
> | [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) | `egrep -r -n --include='*.c' --include='*.h' -w '[A-Z]+_SUSPEND'` | 388 | 0.806s |
>
> And finally, a straight-up comparison between ripgrep, ugrep and GNU grep on a
> single large file cached in memory
> (~13GB, [`OpenSubtitles.raw.en.gz`](http://opus.nlpl.eu/download.php?f=OpenSubtitles/v2018/mono/OpenSubtitles.raw.en.gz)):
>
> | Tool | Command | Line count | Time |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ripgrep | `rg -w 'Sherlock [A-Z]\w+'` | 7882 | **2.769s** |
> | [ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) | `ugrep -w 'Sherlock [A-Z]\w+'` | 7882 | 6.802s |
> | [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) | `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 egrep -w 'Sherlock [A-Z]\w+'` | 7882 | 9.027s |

Comment: I'm shocked that `git grep -P` is faster than `LC_ALL=C git grep -E` since the regexp engine for EREs is usually touted as faster than the one for PCREs (https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) and adding `LC_ALL=C` is usually touted as a way to speed up `grep` in general.

Comment: For that last table where they're simply greping in a large file, it'd have been useful to see the GNU grep result of `LC_ALL=C grep -E -w ...` rather than or in addition to the `LC_ALL=en_us.UTF-8` numbers.